# Prevent Bootstrap modal automatically showing on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

In my case, I have a bootstrap modal to launch on a button click. But when the page loads, an empty modal opens. How can I prevent this? I tried several methods, sometimes modal not loading on the page load but when the button click it's not open. what is the better solution for that?

below codes I tried

```js
                    // $('#empDetailsModal').show();
                    // $('.modal-dialog').show();
                    // $('.modal-backdrop').css("display", "");

                $('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');
                // $('#empDetailsModal').show();
                // $('.modal').addClass('show');
                // $('.modal-dialog').show()
                // $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('hide');
                // $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('show');
```

Here is the code I call to this Modal,

```js
//? show employee details of a selected job
$(document).on('click','#empDetailsBtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // $('#clearFilter').val(emp_id+" "+job_id);
    // $('#filterByDate').val(emp_id+" "+job_id);
    // $('#filterByTime').val(emp_id+" "+job_id);

    //window.emp_id = $(this).val();

    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000,
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/job_employee_details',
        data: {
            job_id: $(this).val()
        }
    })
    .done(function(res) {
        if(res == 'no_data'){
            //console.log(res)
            Toast.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'No Details!'
            })
        }
        else{
            //console.log(res)
            $.each(res.details, function(index, value) {
                //console.log(window.emp_id);
                    $('#emp_details_table_body').append(
                        "<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+ value.firstname + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"+ value.lastname + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"+ value.category + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>"+ 
                            "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='removeJobBtn' emp_id='"+value.emp_id+"' job_id='"+value.job_id+"'>Remove</button>" +  
                        "</td>"
                        +"</tr>"
                    );
                
        // Modal show
                $('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');

            });
        }
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log('error')    
    });
});
```

Here is my Modal code,

```html
<!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="empDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 750px">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Assigned Employee Details</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" id="empDetailsModalcloseIcon" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal_body">

                <table class="table" style="background: #cccccc08">
                    <thead class="bg-primary">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
                        <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="emp_details_table_body">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="empDetailsModalClose">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
```

I'm stuck in this problem several days. So thanks in advance if you can help me!

Comment: Please provide the whole code so that we can see your setup. Snippet is not enough to narrow down your error

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VoFnc4t i found adminlte.css try to open modal

Answer (score 0):

In your JS document ready call you can add `.modal('hide')` like below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide')
});
```

Where `'#myModal'` is the referance to your modal.

Also make sure you are not calling `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` outside of your button click handler.

Comment: In your JS code have you referanced `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` outside of your on click handler?

Comment: i used `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` in AJAX success response

Comment: What happens if you move the `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` outside of the $.each call. So move it below `});`

Comment: I did that, but the same result :(

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to view the mimum working example; but, looking at the call; the `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` is being called inside the AJAX response so this will always open once the `'/job_employee_details'` is loaded. Have you tried moving the `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` outside of the AJAX call? at the bottom.

Comment: i commented the  `$('#empDetailsModal').modal('show');` code. but still Modal is loading

Comment: Are you able to provide the HTML for the modal as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221004/discussion-between-hashan-and-jake-b).